# Xamarin Forms View Does Not Update With Custom Class

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism-6

I'm using Prism.Unity.Forms with Xamarin for this project.  How can I get the view to update when the `Client.Id` property changes?  The view updates when I change the XAML from `{Binding Client.Id}` (a Guid object) to `{Binding Client.Name}`(a string).

```
public class CreateClientViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Client _client;
    public Client Client {
        get => _client;
        set => SetProperty(ref _client, value);
    }

    private async void FetchNewClient()
    {
        Client = new Client{
            Id = new Guid.Parse("501f1302-3a45-4138-bdb7-05c01cd9fe71"),
            Name = "MyClientName"
        };
    }
}
```

This works

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Client.Name}"/>
```

This does not

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Client.Id}"/>
```

I know the `ToString` method is being called on the `Client.Id` property because I wrapped the `Guid` in a custom class and overrode the `ToString` method, but the view still doesn't update.

```
public class CreateClientViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private Client _client;
    public Client Client {
        get => _client;
        set => SetProperty(ref _client, value);
    }

    //This method will eventually make an API call.
    private async void FetchNewClient()
    {
        Client = new Client{
            Id = new ClientId{
                Id = new Guid.Parse("501f1302-3a45-4138-bdb7-05c01cd9fe71")
            },
            Name = "MyClientName"
        };
    }
}

public class ClientId
{
    public Guid Id { get; set }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        //This method gets called
        Console.WriteLine("I GET CALLED");
        return Id.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: be sure to make your Client implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Converter` fixed the problem, though I can't explain why.  The `Guid.ToString` method was being called either way.

`<Entry Text="{Binding Client.Id, Converter={StaticResource GuidConverter}}"/>`

```
public class GuidConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert()
    {
        var guid = (Guid) value;
        return guid.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(){...}
}
```

Then I registered the converter in `App.xaml`

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <viewHelpers:GuidConverter x:Key="GuidConverter" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```